# Difference between $route.current.pathParams and $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update a url without refreshing my page and i'm working with this solution: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699#issuecomment-45048054

I notice that this code works:

```
$route.current.pathParams.program = "someValue";
$location.path('/myapp/' + $routeParams.program);
```

But this code does NOT work:

```
$routeParams.program = "someValue";
$location.path('/myapp/' + $routeParams.program);
```

I'm wondering what the difference is and why one works but not the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because AngularJS does not recognize any changes to `$routeParams` until after the route changes, per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

> Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change
>   completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on
>   $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can
>   use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.